# Can't log in and can't use tty1

Tags: boot, login

When I try to log in all I get is a black screen for a few seconds, before reverting to the login screen.
If I try to press "<kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Alt</kbd> + <kbd>F1</kbd>" (of <kbd>F2</kbd>, <kbd>F3</kbd> etc.) all I get is a black screen which doesn't respond to anything I write. I've also tried to hold shift on boot, which didn't do anything either.

Is there something I've forgot? How can i fix this? I'd really love some help. Thanks.

Comment: Those problems are related to your graphics card. http://www.webupd8.org/2014/01/how-to-fix-non-bootable-ubuntu-system.html might be a method (but instead of `updating` do `sudo dpkg-reconfigure xserver-xorg` and answer the questions).